# String or Byte array. error even use of Column Encryption Setting=enabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, always-encrypted

I use `always encryption` in some field with any of master key stores(I was test all of these):

-current user

-local machine

-CNG

even from application side configure this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DataContext" connectionString="data source=our-PC\SS2016;initial catalog=testdb;integrated security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;Column Encryption Setting=enabled" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When running in web and want to load some data using EF by this block of code :

```
var datas = context.tbUsers.ToList();
```

Below error occured:

> Additional information: The property 'Name' is not a String or Byte
>   array. Length can only be configured for String and Byte array
>   properties.

What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must be careful of using of Enum type
one filed of one of the table property  have a enum type which is Prohibited

I Changed the propery and programs run okay